# Checking if RPC endpoint URL is hidden in a react front end

Tags: rpc, frontend, endpoint

I've heard different things from different people on this front, but i've been looking into trying to keep api details (keys, rpc end point urls etc) hidden in a react front-end application.

I've made a simple devnet application  (https://www.daoplays.org/blog/serverless_solana) that is using a private RPC end point, and was wondering how to actually go about checking if the url is hidden or not.

The site is hosted by netlify, and I am using their 'serverless' functions to act as the intermediary, so I can see on the network tab that I am hitting my netlify endpoints, and can't see any record of the actual RPC endpoint, but i'm not an expert in this kind of thing, and was hoping someone here might be!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't make any definitive claims here, but it seems obvious to me that one could always just go to the network tab of their browser's inspector to see all the network traffic going on. Or they could open up Wireshark and do the same thing at a much deeper level.

The fundamental problem is if you want your packets to get to destination A, well you can't make that happen without at some point being honest about where A (or a reverse proxy to it, etc) is. In this case, that's got to happen client-side (since it has to occur inside of your frontend), and that necessarily is going to occur in a place where the user has complete and total visibility over all network traffic leaving their machine.